# Parallelizing matrix computations with Numba

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, numba, heavy-computation

I am trying to parallelise the following function in Python 3.6:

```
def get_Q(predictors, d):
    Q = 0.
    for i in range(len(predictors)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(predictors)):
            ci = predictors[i,:]
            cj = predictors[j,:]
            Q += product_cols(ci, cj, d[i], d[j])
    return Q
```

where :
 `predictors[,]` is an input array, with **`n`**-rows and **`p`**-features, and
`d[]` is an **`n`**-sized array.

The function `product_cols()` is defined as :

```
def product_cols(ci, cj, di, dj):
    c = ci-cj
    return np.matmul(np.transpose(np.matrix(c)), np.matrix(c))*((di-dj)**2)
```

where :
`ci[]`, `cj[]` are **`p`**-sized arrays and
`di, dj` are real numbers.

Could someone help me to parallelise this simply?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you trying to achieve

Comment: Is that function meant to work on NumPy arrays? Also, is there any particular reason you’re using `numpy.matrix`?